# Вставить в бинарное дерево узел

Tags: python-3.x, алгоритм, бинарное-дерево

Эта программа с помощью бинарного дерева выводит предложения "Three cats playing football"
И нужно вставить в дерево узел, чтобы получилось предложение: "Three cats playing table football"

```
class Node(object):
  def __init__(self,value):
    self.value = value
    self.left = None
    self.right = None

class BinaryTree(object):

  def __init__(self,root):
    self.root = Node(root)

  def print_tree(self,traversal_type):
    if traversal_type == "preorder":
      return self.preorder_print(tree.root, "")
    else:
      print('Traverasl type ' + str(traversal_type) + 'is not supported')
      return False

  def preorder_print(self,start,traversal):
    if start:
      traversal += (str(start.value) + '-')
      traversal = self.preorder_print(start.left,traversal)
      traversal = self.preorder_print(start.right,traversal)
    return traversal
#                      Three
#                           \
#                            cats
#                          /      \
#                      playing   football         

tree = BinaryTree('Three')
tree.root.right = Node('cats')
tree.root.right.left = Node('playing')
tree.root.right.right = Node('football')

print(tree.print_tree("preorder"))
```

Comment: Так, и в чем вопрос? Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: `tree.root.right.left.left = Node('table')`